# Variable not being picked up

Tags: php

In my config.php file I have a variable that is set to 'localhost'.

```
 $CONFIG['MySQLi']['host'] = "localhost";
```

However, when I include this config.php in my database class, I test it by calling the variable in an echo through the __construct() method

```
 public function __construct() {
      echo $CONFIG['MySQLi']['host'];
 }
```

But then for some reason, I get this error:

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: CONFIG in C:\xampp\htdocs\Muse\classes\class.database.php on line 15
```

However I get no errors for importing the config.php file. Would someone be able to explain why this is happening? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who still wants the answer to this question, another good way to do it is by DEFINING a variable.

```
define('VARIABLE', 'VALUE');
```

And then call it by doing VARIABLE. E.g.

```
<?php echo VARIABLE; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The function doesn't know about variables that were defined outside due to [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php).

```
public function __construct() {
    global $CONFIG;

}
```

should resolve this. However, this is usually considered bad practice.

---

Alternatively you can use static attributes as shown by [Kohjah Breese](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20386102/1557526), pass the config array to the constructor (as suggested by *AlexP*) or use a construct like the following.

*/config/mysqli.php*

```
<?php
return array(
   //what now is $CONFIG['MySQLi']
);
```

and in the function

```
public function __construct() {
    $config = include '/config/mysqli.php';
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thankyou, I will mark your question right when it allows me

Comment: +1 As another option you could pass it in as a function argument `__construct($config)`

Comment: I don't quite get the new suggestion?

Comment: Instead of one config file you'd have many (of course this'd work with one just as well). In this you don't just define the array (`$CONFIG = array(...)`) but return it (`return array(...);`)! Now you don't just include but assign the included value to a variable (which will now hold the array)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thankyou for your help, and everybody else too. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

AS above, function do not have access to standard variables stored outside of them, but a better solution is to create a class you want to store global variables in. I use something like this:

```
class Conf 
{ 

    // Project
    static $CODE = 'F';
    static $NAME = 'For';
    static $ACCESS = 'public';
    static $CHARSET = 'utf-8';
    static $DATA = array();
    static $CACHE = false;
    static $HTMLINDENT = true;

    // Diagnostic
    static $SHOWEXECTIME = true;

    // Paths
    static $PATH_FILESYSTEM = '';
    static $PATH_CORE = '/var/www/sites/core';
    static $PATH_DOMAIN = 'localhost';
    static $PATH_URL = 'http://localhost/sites/for/';
    static $PATH_CACHE = 'cache/';
    static $PATH_CSS = 'css/';
    static $PATH_DATA = 'data/';
    static $PATH_JS = 'js/';
    static $PATH_LOG = 'logs/';
    static $PATH_XML = 'xml/';
    static $PATH_XSL = 'xsl/';

    // DB Details
    static $DB_USER = 'root';
    static $DB_PASS = 'pass';
    static $DB_DSN = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=for;charset=utf8';

}
```

My tests showed this to be the quickest solution. Some people use constants, which are very slow. Globals have been depreciated, and are a security risk.

You can access any of these vars from anywhere in PHP using Conf::$NAME; etc.